# Change the the path of backup files in ansible playbook while using backup=yes with lineinfile module

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

How can we change the path of backup files while using lineinfile module in an ansible playbook with backup = yes.The issue is the that the backup files are stored in the same directory which is causing the nginx service to fail everytime it is restarted using handler

```
- name: Down1
  lineinfile: backup=yes
              state=present
              dest=/etc/nginx/conf.d/new.conf
              regexp='^  server {{ groups['target'][1] }}:8080;'
              line='  server {{ groups['target'][1] }}:8080 down;'
  when: (groups['target'][0] == inventory_hostname) and (status == "down1")
  notify: Restart nginx
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is IMHO currently not possible change to folder of backup files in Ansible. There is an [open issue on github](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/16305) for this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the info :)